# Why I am unable to join these two code ESP32 and ICM42688

Tags: esp32, imu

I have two sepparate codes, one is to interface ICM42688 to implement a shake to wake feature while ESP is in deep sleep, the other one is to force sleep or wake esp32. Those two works fine when tested on by one, but when I combine them, then the combined code stops working. The combined code is supposed to:

- Make ESP sleep using the built-in push button.
- Wake ESP with shake using ICM42688 or using the push button
- Once awake then should go back to sleep with the push button

CODE 1:

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "ICM42688.h"

// an ICM42688 object with the ICM42688 sensor on SPI bus 0 and chip select pin 10
ICM42688 IMU(SPI, 13);

// Which pin on the Arduino is connected to the NeoPixels?
#define PIN 15  // Pin 12

// How many NeoPixels are attached to the Arduino?
#define NUMPIXELS 8  // Popular NeoPixel ring size

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

#define BUTTON_PIN_BITMASK 0x200000000  // 2^33 in hex

RTC_DATA_ATTR bool boot = 0;

bool calibratePressed = true;
bool buttonPressed = true;

unsigned long timer = 0;
uint16_t counter = 0;
// volatile bool wake_sleep = false;
// volatile unsigned long buttonPressStartTime = 0;
// volatile byte buttonCounter = 0;
// byte jumperState = 0;

const int calibrate_sleep_wakePin = 38;  // Use GPIO 38 (user switch) pin for the calibrate_sleep_wake-up

float referenceAccX, referenceAccY, referenceAccZ;
float referenceGyrX, referenceGyrY, referenceGyrZ;
float dynamicThreshold;

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  // serial to display data
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {}

  // start communication with IMU
  int status = IMU.begin();
  if (status < 0) {
    Serial.println("IMU initialization unsuccessful");
    Serial.println("Check IMU wiring or try cycling power");
    Serial.print("Status: ");
    Serial.println(status);
    while (1) {}
  }
  pixels.begin();
  // attaching the interrupt to microcontroller pin 1
  pinMode(33, INPUT);
  pinMode(calibrate_sleep_wakePin, INPUT);
  // attachInterrupt(33, setImuFlag, RISING);
  // set output data rate to 12.5 Hz
  IMU.setAccelODR(ICM42688::odr12_5);
  IMU.setGyroODR(ICM42688::odr12_5);

  // enabling the data ready interrupt
  IMU.enableDataReadyInterrupt();

  Serial.println("ax,ay,az,gx,gy,gz,temp_C");

  boot = !boot;

  esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO_NUM_33, 1);  //1 = High, 0 = Low
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(calibrate_sleep_wakePin) == LOW && buttonPressed == true) {
    buttonPressed = false;
    calibratePressed = true;
  } else if (digitalRead(calibrate_sleep_wakePin) == HIGH && buttonPressed == false) {
    buttonPressed = true;
  }

  if (calibratePressed) {
    Serial.println("Calibrating and powering on/off...");

    // Reset the orientation to 0, 0, 0
    referenceAccX = referenceAccY = referenceAccZ = 0.0;
    referenceGyrX = referenceGyrY = referenceGyrZ = 0.0;

    // read the sensor
    IMU.getAGT();

    // Subtract reference values to obtain calibrated values
    float calibratedAccX = IMU.accX() - referenceAccX;
    float calibratedAccY = IMU.accY() - referenceAccY;
    float calibratedAccZ = IMU.accZ() - referenceAccZ;
    float calibratedGyrX = IMU.gyrX() - referenceGyrX;
    float calibratedGyrY = IMU.gyrY() - referenceGyrY;
    float calibratedGyrZ = IMU.gyrZ() - referenceGyrZ;

    // Calculate the dynamic threshold based on calibrated values
    dynamicThreshold = calculateDynamicThreshold(calibratedAccX, calibratedAccY, calibratedAccZ);

    Serial.println("Calibration complete.");

    calibratePressed = false;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        pixels.setPixelColor(j, pixels.Color(0, 255, 0));
      }
      pixels.show();  // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.
      delay(300);
      for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        pixels.setPixelColor(j, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      }
      pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.
      pixels.clear();  // Set all pixel colors to 'off'
      delay(300);
    }
  }

  // read the sensor
  IMU.getAGT();

  // Subtract reference values to obtain calibrated values
  float calibratedAccX = IMU.accX() - referenceAccX;
  float calibratedAccY = IMU.accY() - referenceAccY;
  float calibratedAccZ = IMU.accZ() - referenceAccZ;
  float calibratedGyrX = IMU.gyrX() - referenceGyrX;
  float calibratedGyrY = IMU.gyrY() - referenceGyrY;
  float calibratedGyrZ = IMU.gyrZ() - referenceGyrZ;

  // display the calibrated data
  Serial.print(calibratedAccX, 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(calibratedAccY, 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(calibratedAccZ, 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(calibratedGyrX, 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(calibratedGyrY, 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(calibratedGyrZ, 6);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(IMU.temp(), 6);

  if (isShakeDetected(calibratedAccX, calibratedAccY, calibratedAccZ, dynamicThreshold)) {
    // Add your code to wake up the device or perform any other action
    Serial.println("Shake detected! Wake up or perform an action.");

    counter = 0;
  } else {
    if(millis() - timer >= 1) {
      counter++;

      if(counter >= 5000) {
        counter = 0;
        Serial.println("Going to Sleep!!!");
        esp_deep_sleep_start();
      }
    }
  }
}

bool isShakeDetected(float accX, float accY, float accZ, float threshold) {
  // Calculate the magnitude of acceleration
  float accelerationMagnitude = sqrt(pow(accX, 2) + pow(accY, 2) + pow(accZ, 2));

  // Check if the magnitude exceeds the dynamic threshold
  return accelerationMagnitude > threshold;
}

float calculateDynamicThreshold(float calibratedAccX, float calibratedAccY, float calibratedAccZ) {
  // You can customize this function based on your requirements
  // For example, return a percentage of the maximum calibrated acceleration magnitude
  float maxCalibratedAcc = max(abs(calibratedAccX), max(abs(calibratedAccY), abs(calibratedAccZ)));
  return 1.0 * maxCalibratedAcc;  // Adjust the multiplier as needed
}
```

CODE 2:

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

// Which pin on the Arduino is connected to the NeoPixels?
#define PIN 15  // Pin 15

// How many NeoPixels are attached to the Arduino?
#define NUMPIXELS 8  // Popular NeoPixel ring size

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

volatile bool calibratePressed = false;
volatile bool buttonPressed = false;
volatile bool wake_sleep_ext = true;
volatile bool wake_sleep_tmr = true;
volatile unsigned long buttonPressStartTime = 0;
volatile unsigned int buttonCounter = 0;

#define uS_TO_mS_FACTOR 100000ULL /* Conversion factor for micro seconds to seconds */
#define TIME_TO_SLEEP 1           /* Time ESP32 will go to sleep (in seconds) */

const int calibrate_sleep_wakePin = 38;  // Use GPIO 38 (user switch) pin for the calibrate_sleep_wake-up

typedef enum {
  Yellow,
  Orange,
  Green
} color_t;

typedef enum {
  One,
  Two,
  Three,
  Four,
  Five,
  Six,
  Seven,
  Eight
} leds_t;

void setup() {
  // serial to display data
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Set up Calibrate button pin
  pinMode(calibrate_sleep_wakePin, INPUT);

  pixels.begin();

  force_wake_up();
  // wake_up();
}

void loop() {
  // Check if the Calibrate button is pressed
  
  if (calibratePressed) {

    pixels.clear();

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(255, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 255, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(2, pixels.Color(0, 0, 255));
      pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(255, 255, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(0, 255, 255));
      pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(255, 0, 255));
      pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));
      pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));

      pixels.show();  // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

      delay(300);

      pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(2, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
      pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));

      pixels.show();  // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

      delay(300);
    }
    pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(255, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 255, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(2, pixels.Color(0, 0, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(255, 255, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(0, 255, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(255, 0, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));

    pixels.show();  // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.
    calibratePressed = false;
  }

  if(digitalRead(calibrate_sleep_wakePin) == LOW && buttonPressed == false) {
    buttonPressed = true;
    delay(100);
    while((digitalRead(calibrate_sleep_wakePin) == LOW)) {
      delay(1);
      buttonCounter++;
      if(buttonCounter >= 2000) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if(buttonCounter < 2000) {
      buttonCounter = 0;
      calibratePressed = true;
    }
    if(buttonCounter >= 2000) {
      wake_sleep_ext = true;
      buttonCounter = 0;
    }
    sleep();
  } else if(digitalRead(calibrate_sleep_wakePin) == HIGH && buttonPressed == true) {
    delay(200);
    buttonPressed = false;
  }
}

void sleep() {
  if (wake_sleep_ext) {
    buttonPressed = false;
    wake_sleep_tmr = true;
    Serial.println("Going to sleep...");

    pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(2, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));

    pixels.show();  // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.
    // Enter deep sleep mode
    esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP * uS_TO_mS_FACTOR);
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
  } else {
    // Stop watchdog timer
    pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(255, 0, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 255, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(2, pixels.Color(0, 0, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(255, 255, 0));
    pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(0, 255, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(255, 0, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));
    pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));

    pixels.show();  // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.
    
    esp_sleep_disable_wakeup_source(ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TIMER);
  }
}

void force_wake_up() {
  if(wake_sleep_tmr == true) {
    if(digitalRead(calibrate_sleep_wakePin) == LOW) {
      buttonPressed = true;
      delay(100);
      while((digitalRead(calibrate_sleep_wakePin) == LOW)) {
        delay(1);
        buttonCounter++;
        if(buttonCounter >= 500) {
          wake_sleep_ext = false;
          wake_sleep_tmr = false;
          esp_sleep_disable_wakeup_source(ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TIMER);
          buttonCounter = 0;
          pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(255, 0, 0));
          pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(0, 255, 0));
          pixels.setPixelColor(2, pixels.Color(0, 0, 255));
          pixels.setPixelColor(3, pixels.Color(255, 255, 0));
          pixels.setPixelColor(4, pixels.Color(0, 255, 255));
          pixels.setPixelColor(5, pixels.Color(255, 0, 255));
          pixels.setPixelColor(6, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));
          pixels.setPixelColor(7, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));

          pixels.show();  // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the combined code and how or where does it stop working?